# "Cannot create an instance of class" when trying to use hilt view model with Jetpack Composable - dagger Hilt + Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack, dagger-hilt

I am trying to use a `TodoViewModel` inside a `@Composable` in `MainActivity`

`MainActivity.kt`

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            TodoBasicsTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    TodoInput()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TodoInput(
    todoViewModel: TodoViewModel = hiltViewModel()
){
    // val todoViewModel: TodoViewModel = viewModel()
    // val todoViewModel: TodoViewModel = hiltViewModel()

    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("Hello") }

    Row() {
        InputField(text = text, onValueChanged = { text = it }, label = "Enter Todo")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
        ExtendedFloatingActionButton(onClick = {
            todoViewModel.saveTodo(title = text)
        }) {
            Text(text = "Add")
        }
    }
}
```

`TodoViewModel.kt`

```kotlin
package com.example.todobasics.viewModel

imports...

@HiltViewModel
class TodoViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val todoRepository: TodoRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    val LOG_TAG = "todoViewModel"
    init {
        println("Hello")
    }
    fun saveTodo(title: String){
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Saving Todo")

        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default){
            todoRepository.insertTodo(Todo(title=title))
        }
    }
}
```

Error Message

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.todobasics, PID: 6503

java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.todobasics.viewModel.TodoViewModel
```

I am also adding my `AppModule` and `build.gradle` for additional information

`AppModule.kt`

```kotlin
package com.example.todobasics.di

imports...

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideTripMemoryDatabase(app: Application): TodoDatabase{
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            app,
            TodoDatabase::class.java,
            "todo_db"
        ).build()

    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideTodoRepository(db: TodoDatabase): TodoRepository{
        return TodoRepository(db.todoDao)
    }
}
```

`build.gradle (:app)`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.todobasics'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.todobasics"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.2'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation platform('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0')
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
    // Compose Navigation
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version") // 2.5.3
    // Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")

    // Dagger Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$dagger_version"
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0")

    // ViewModel
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$lifecycle_version")

}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To enable members injection in your activity, annotate your class with **@AndroidEntryPoint**.

You forget to add **@AndroidEntryPoint** on MainActivity, Just Add It And You will have no error

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
    class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
            setContent {
                TodoBasicsTheme {
                    // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                    Surface(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                    ) {
                        TodoInput()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Composable
    fun TodoInput(
        todoViewModel: TodoViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    ){
        // val todoViewModel: TodoViewModel = viewModel()
        // val todoViewModel: TodoViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    
        var text by remember { mutableStateOf("Hello") }
    
        Row() {
            InputField(text = text, onValueChanged = { text = it }, label = "Enter Todo")
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
            ExtendedFloatingActionButton(onClick = {
                todoViewModel.saveTodo(title = text)
            }) {
                Text(text = "Add")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How to use it with a  composable that is written outside of the MainActivity / a component

Comment: You just have to annotate one main component then after you can use it anywhere. because It it basically children's of main tree